# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im trying very basic example of google apis at http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/?s=GPS.
I've done the coding part & tried to install on AVD. I'm getting error . [Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY].

I installed Google apis for API Level 7 & 8.I added  between Application tag. I'm not getting what's the error. I've done lot of searching also. Please somebody can help.

here is my manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.position"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <uses-library android:name="”com.google.android.maps”" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: you will make change in this line and try it out                 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

Comment: god thats the thing.thanks Selva.Im such a fool :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change like this

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: Thanks mukesh'' This line is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register [google API maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup)?

My Manifest.XML it's like:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:icon="@raw/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".VentanaIP"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".VentanaMapa"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />     
</application>

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:apiKey="xxXXXXXxxXXXxxXXXXXxxXXXXX"
             />
```

Comment: Thanks AlexMuni'' I had a error in my syntax. Anyway thanks for quick reply.

Comment: yes, but you need `<com.google.android.maps.MapView ....` to register you apiKey ;)